# Как сделать слайдер из div блоков на javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, слайдер

Подскажите пожалуйста, нужно сделать слайдер на сайт как на картинке. При клике на стрелку или пагинацию блок должен меняться.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужно сесть и написать код...

Comment: На [хабре десятки статей исписаны](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%20site%3Ahabr.com&lr=213&clid=2186621) по тому как делаются слайдеры, попробуйте любую конкетную статью взять и по ней сделать. Пока вопрос слишком общий.

Comment: Может кто-кто подскажет какой слайдер можно использовать чтобы получилось как на картинке?

Answer (score 1):

Могу подсказать - при нажатии на стрелки надо сделать так что вся галерея сдвигалась налево, то есть делаем сразу же всю галерею и пространство где она будет отображаться. А потом кнопками просто сдвигаем (приписываем свойство `left/right`)